# Autologin and launch application - Terminal Kiosk

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, systemd

I am on CentOS and I have modified systemd agetty scripts to autologin successfully based on
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Getty

I want to auto-launch an application after the user is logged in and if for some reason, if the application crashes, it should logout and respawn the shell and start the application. At any point I do not want the user to break out to a shell from the application.

Basically kiosk mode on terminal. Any ideas, how it can be done.